# using ExpressionVisitor how to dynamically get evaluate value of expression of a ParameterExpression

Tags: c#, expressionvisitor

I have an expression that takes an expression as one of its parameters:

[image]

I am using a ExpressionVisitor to get the values of constants [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754903/deconstructing-methodcallexpressions-when-passing-parameters-into-the-expression).

but if a member is a memberAccess type I want to be able to evaluate what the actual value would be of that parameter.  In this example, `($obj.Name).Length`.

the example wants to check if an int (first value) is greater than the second value (in this case the expression).  If it is a constant I know how to get the value of those, but I can't figure out how to evaluate the expression on the fly.

I have passed the whole object and the whole expression into the ExpressionVisitor so that they are available to be used to help if required.

```cs
internal class ValueExtractor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly object _item;
    private readonly MethodCallExpression _wholeExpression;

    public List<object> Arguments { get; }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
       if (memberType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
       {
           var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(node, false, NotSureAboutThis);
           exp.Compile().Invoke(NotSureWhichPropGoesHere);
       }

    }
}
```

The node value in VisitMember is:

[image]

I have access to T and TMember.  where T is the main object this is all being called (has property Age) and TMember being int in this case (Age).

I am not sure if the example above is going in the right direction, if it is I am not sure how to finish it up.

Comment: If you wan the value of a sub expression you need to execute the expression with objects you want to read the value. A parametar doesn't have any value its a container indicating a value will be there at runtime of the expression.

Comment: @FilipCordas I don't understand you response.  When the whole expression is invoked it returns a boolean value, (see first screen shot).  it will not tell me what the inner expression value is (see second screen shot). if you mean I should execute the sub expression, that is what I am not sure about how to do, hence the post

Comment: Let's say you have the following code `Expression<Func<string, int>> exp = (s) => s.Length + 5;

            ExpressionVisitor ve = new ValueExtractor();

            ve.Visit(exp);` how can you know what the length of the string is when you are not actually calling the expression. With constants you can get the value because they exist before you do invoke on the expression. If you know what arguments are in your invoke you could get the length of the string.